# Bluetooth not Working on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, bluetooth

Well I had the problem that bluetooth was always off. I go to configuration->Bluetooth and every time I tried to put it on just returns to off a while after. I tried with this command:

```
aptitude install bluetooth
```

and then run

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

after that I runed `/etc/init.d/bluetooth status` and this is what shows:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-01-17 21:13:47 UTC; 29s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 7939 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─7939 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: Error adding Link Loss service
Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: Not enough free handles to register ...ce
Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: Not enough free handles to register ...ce
Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: Not enough free handles to register ...ce
Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: Current Time Service could not be re...ed
Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: Not enough free handles to register ...ce
Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: Not enough free handles to register ...ce
Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jan 17 21:13:47 kali bluetoothd[7939]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

My computer is a sony VAIO SVF15A17CLV.

Output from `rfkill list all`

```
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

1. `apt-get install bluetooth`
2. `lsmod | grep bluetooth`
3. `/etc/init.d/bluetooth status`
4. `/etc/init.d/bluetooth start`

Answer (score -4):

Use this command as it should work:

```
service bluetooth restart
```

Comment: Not even this is working